# C# Which loop to use?

Tags: c#

I can't remove the item using this type of loop (foreach), which loop should i use? (that will return my variables) if that makes any sense. Thank you all help is very much so appreciated! Be easy on me i'm not too experienced. If that doesn't make sense i'm really trying to find any way to basically make my program so that for each ip address, it will try my username and password combination (that are loaded into list like user:pass), i'm doing this because i have set up hundreds of proxies in the past with different user/pass & i'm checking to see if they work still. Thanks

```
 var l = loadips();
            var t = func();
            Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string ip = ip_item.IP;
                    try {
                        foreach (var blah2 in t)
                        {
                            String[] fc = blah2.test.Split(':');
                            var u = fc[0];
                            var p = fc[1];
                            using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip, u, p))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(u + p + ip_item.IP);
                                client.Connect();
                                ip_item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
                                client.Disconnect();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                       // t.Remove(blah2);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ip_item.IP + " - BAD!");
                    l.Remove(ip_item);
                }
            });
            foreach (var item in l)
            {
                if (item.AcceptsConnection == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ip + " Working proxy.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't modify the collection through which you're iterating, whatever loop you use. To achieve your objective, simply add the working data to another list.

```
var working = new ConcurrentBag<IpItem>(); // not sure what your type is
[....]
using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip, u, p))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(u + p + ip_item.IP);
                            client.Connect();
                            ip_item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
                            client.Disconnect();
                            working.Add(ip_item);
                        }
```

Then, at the end, get all working results from working, and output as needed

Comment: doesn't really answer what i mean, my obstacle at the moment is trying to find a way to make sure each combination is being tested in a loop until it has attempted all login combinations

Comment: You have your combination in one collection, which you are looping through, from start to end, and you want to end up with a set of working logins. Your proposed solution is to remove non-working ones from the collection, so that only working ones remain. This is logically fine, but causes problems with your loop (and has threading/loop boundry issues). Another solution is to instead add the working ones to another collection. My code snippet is suggested modifications to your code, not a whole solution

Answer (score 1):

NO, you can't use `foreach` loop for removing an item from the collection; very basic reason because the loop iterator of `foreach` is `ReadOnly`. You should choose to use `for` loop for that purpose.

Check [MSDN reference for foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). As it clearly says

> The `foreach` statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove
>   items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.
>   If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a
>   `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using another list to identify the failures.

```
var l = loadips();
var t = func();

var faileds = new ConcurrentQueue<YourClass>();

Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) =>
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ip_item.IP + " - BAD!");
        faileds.Enqueue(ip_item);
    }
});

foreach (var item in l.Except(faileds))
{
    if (item.AcceptsConnection == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ip + " Working proxy.");
    }
}
```

And for "all combination", I suggest you list out all combinations first.

```
var combinations = l.SelectMany(ipItem =>
    t.Select(blah2 => Tuple.Create(ipItem, blah2)).ToArray();

foreach (var combination in combinations)
{
    var ip = combination.Item1.IP;
    var fc = combination.Item2.Split(':');
    var u = fc[0];
    var p = fc[1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about  finding a way to make sure each combination is being tested in a loop until it has attempted all login combinations

Comment: Consider using SelectMany and Tuple to list out all combinations first.